# Connection status - how to call method from another class

Tags: java, android, connection

I wrote application which have to check status if internet connection and I would like to call this method in another class, but I don't know how should I do this.

Here is the code responsible for checking internet connection:

```
public class NetworkUtil {

public static int TYPE_WIFI = 1;
public static int TYPE_MOBILE = 2;
public static int TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED = 0;


public static int getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (null != activeNetwork) {
        if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
            return TYPE_WIFI;

        if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
            return TYPE_MOBILE;
    } 
    return TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;
}

public static String getConnectivityStatusString(Context context) {
    int conn = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(context);
    String status = null;
    if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_WIFI) {
        status = "Wifi enabled";
    } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_MOBILE) {
        status = "Mobile data enabled";
    } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) {
        status = "Not connected to Internet";
    }
    return status;
}
}
```

and broadcast class:

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

        String status = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);

        Toast.makeText(context, status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I would like to check in another class, or at the moment there is no connection (`getConnectivityStatus` return `TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED`) and execute some code like this:

```
if (connection is missing - i don't know what should i put in this place) {
    // other code
}
else {
}
```

**Can you help me?**

Answer (score 0):

```
if (NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(getApplicationContext()) == NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED)  {
  //NOT CONNECTED!
}else {
    //CONNECTED!
}
```

you can also change your method to retrieve a boolean value:

```
public static boolean getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (null != activeNetwork) {
        if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
            return true;

        if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
            return true;
    } 
    return false;
}
```

and your code will be like:

```
if (NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(getApplicationContext()))  {
    //CONNECTED!
}else {
    //NOT CONNECTED!
}
```

**Note:**
If you are inside a fragment you can call your method as:

```
NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
```

Comment: Ok, your code is great, but when i want to call getConnectivityStatus in seperate, another class?

Comment: Call the method referencing the class :  NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(....) and of course adding the import NetworkUtil class.

Comment: but eclipse want from me "create method getApplicationContext()

Comment: are you calling that method inside a fragment? if the answer is "yes" : NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(getActivity().getApplicationContext())

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your problem is...

```
if (NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(getApplicationContext()) == NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED)  {

}else {

}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: but eclipse want from me "create method getApplicationContext() " and i don't know what should i do with this

Comment: Ok so I guess you're in a class that doesn't extend Fragment or Activity. It depends on the architecture of your app, if your class is instantiated in an Activity then you could create a constructor with  the applicationContext as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

here what I made:

First i register my receiver in my activity :

```
   registerReceiver(
              new NetworkChangeReceiver(),
              new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)
    );
```

here is my Receiver:

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "NetworkStateReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.v(TAG, "[status]: " + NetworkUtils.getConnectivityStatus(context));
    }
}
```

and finally my NetworkUtils is as simple as this :

```
public enum NetworkStatus{
    NETWORK_STATUS_NOT_CONNECTED,
    NETWORK_STATUS_WIFI,
    NETWORK_STATUS_MOBILE
}

    public static NetworkStatus getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (null != activeNetwork) {
            if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
                return NetworkStatus.NETWORK_STATUS_WIFI;

            if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
                return NetworkStatus.NETWORK_STATUS_MOBILE;
        }
        return NetworkStatus.NETWORK_STATUS_NOT_CONNECTED;
    }
}
```